# Application Role SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, security, application-role

I would like to set up application role in my sql server to secure my application (.exe) . The goal is to deny all permissions of my Windows users and use the application role to do the differents manipulation.But I have 2 databases (prod and common). So I have 2 application roles and I would like to activate both at the same time.Does someone have an idea ? Thanks

I tried to set up the approle for the first database, then use an impersonate request to set the approle on the second database but it doesn't work

Comment: You don't need an application role to restrict access. A role gives permissions to users, it doesn't act as a user itself. Instead of adding Windows logins directly to the database, put them in groups and add the *groups* to the database. You can map Windows groups to server or database roles and give permissions to the roles, not the individual users. That's how members of the default `public` role can't do much but members of `dbdatareader` can read everything while `db_backupoperator` can take backups even if the user can't read the data

Comment: Use two connections?

Comment: As for why `then use an impersonate request to set the approle on the second database` doesn't work, it's because there's no impersonation involved. The *user* doesn't change. If you want to allow users to only connect through your application using an application role, you'll have to revert and re-activate for each database as shown [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-setapprole-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#b-activating-an-application-role-with-a-cookie-and-then-reverting-to-the-original-context).

Comment: Another possibility could be to use [SYNONYM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) to make Common tables appear as tables inside Production. This way you can use a single application role and *not* give direct access to Common

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos you're confusing a Database Role and and Application Role.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16  vs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/application-roles?view=sql-server-ver16  A Database Role gives permissions to users, an Application Role acts as a user itself.

Comment: Thank you, but I may have misunderstood you. The aim is to remove rights from users so that they cannot access databases via other applications (e.g. Excel). But when I launch my application (AccFin), the user must have access to the databases.

Comment: @KyllianAlland that's indeed one of the very rare scenarios where application roles make sense BUT why do you want that instead of using minimum-privilege custom database roles? Is there a real need or are you assuming this is the solution to some other problem? Application roles have one big problem : Where will you save that password?

Comment: The aim was to activate the role application via the code of another application because in my application, a lot of rights are required but they are only required when the application is active. but I've found another way of securing my database via a trigger on the logon